# ChartJS Annotation issue

Tags: annotations, chart.js

I'm attempting to use a float/double value for my annotation vertical line depicting the mean of a bell curve. When I use the provided annotation plugin for chartjs, it won't let me use a floating value with a decimal.

```
    var opt1 = {
                canvasBorders: true,
                canvasBordersWidth: 3,
                canvasBordersColor: "black",
                legend: true,
                datasetFill: false,
                annotateDisplay: true,
                pointDot: false,
                animationLeftToRight: true,
                animationEasing: "linear",
                yAxisMinimumInterval: 0.02,
                graphTitleFontSize: 18,
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        position: "left",
                        "id": "y-axis-0"
                    }, {
                        position: "right",
                        "id": "y-axis-1"
                    }],
                    xAxes: [{
                        "id": "tots-1",
                    }]
                },
                annotation: {
                    annotations: [{
                        id: 'a-line-1', // optional
                        type: 'line',
                        mode: 'vertical',
                        scaleID: 'tots-1',
                        value: average,
                        borderColor: 'red',
                        borderWidth: 5,}]
                   }
                },
             }
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I am facing the same problem.. Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: I did. I had to actually go into the Chart.controllers.line.prototype.draw = function(ease) and manually add the annotation lines using the canvas methods:

this.chart.chart.ctx.beginPath();
            this.chart.chart.ctx.strokeStyle = '#ff0000';
            this.chart.chart.ctx.moveTo(leftMargin + left, topMargin);
            this.chart.chart.ctx.lineTo(leftMargin + left, scale.top);
            this.chart.chart.ctx.stroke();

Comment: can you please post an example for the same? a fiddle or codepen

Comment: @ProjectUI Please consider posting your solution as answer here :)